# CORS Issue and Status Code 301 when uploading to AWS-S3 using Amazon JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to upload a test file to my public S3 bucket from a web browser. However, I have encountered a CORS issue (which I believe I resolved) and then the status code 301 issue. Perhaps this isn't the right way to do it?

Notes: Bucket Policy and Access Control List is set to public with full write and read control for testing purposes. Bucket policy and roles also provide full privileges.

When I run my function to upload I get this error.

```
Failed to load https://{bucket-name}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testfile.txt: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

However, CORS on my bucket has been set with the following CORS configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"> <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> </CORSRule> </CORSConfiguration>
```

So I installed a CORS chrome extension (Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *) and the error disappeared. However now I get this error.

```
1) Failed to load https://{bucket-name}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testfile.txt: 
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 301. 
2) Error: Network Failure
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (aws-sdk.js:125425)
```

When I try to access that link I can see the following XML.

```
<Error>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
```

This is strange as I am using the latest amazon SDK and am using their upload api. So this is where I am stuck. Here is my code I am attempting to run.

**JS**

Using https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.207.0.min.js

```
var f = new File(["This is a test file"], "filename.txt", {type: "text/plain"});

var paramsObj = {Bucket: 'mybucketname'};

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'myaccessID', secretAccessKey: 'mysecretaccesskey', region: 'us-east-2'
});

var s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  params: paramsObj
});

function testUpload(){
  s3.upload({
    Key: "testfile.txt",
    Body: f,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return alert('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
    }
  });
}
```

Things I have tried that didn't work.

- Host on ec2 machine and access over the domain on port 80 still has the CORS issue, enabling plugin results in same error
- Use Cognito Identity Pool ID as shown in amazon's example results in same issue

Things I am currently attempting.

- I will setup a node server on ec2 that I can upload to, and then the ec2 server will upload to the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 4):

The error for the 301 redirect points to the URL endpoint not being valid. This means that the configuration for the aws was not setup correctly. Upon further review a co-worker discovered that the region was incorrect and that it was *'us-east-1'* instead of *'us-east-2'*.

Adding the region to the paramsObj and update to the correct region fixes this issue.

The reason why this confusion occurred is that the console URL which I used to view the bucket ended with

```
?region=us-east-2
```

However, this does not relate to the bucket location at all as you can change the region or remove it and it will point to the same console page.

Comment: Thanks, it worked !! In my case my bucket region was "us-east-2" and I was using "us-west-2"